# division of very large integers in Python using SageMath

Tags: python, math

I'm implementing Wiener's Exponent Attack using Python and SageMath.

My code is as follows

```py
from sage.all import *
# constants
b = some_very_large_number
n = some_very_large_number
b_over_n = continued_fraction(b/n)

while True:
    t_over_a = b_over_n.convergent(i+1)
    t = t_over_a.numerator()
    a = t_over_a.denominator()
    # check if t divides ab-1
    if ((t != 0) and (gcd(a*b-1, t)== t)):
        print("Found i: ", i)
        break
    i += 1
```

I found out that the loop would not end forever and added this line of code before the while loop.

```
print(b_over_n.convergent(5))
```

And I found that `b_over_n` was always returning 0 no matter what.
I also printed out `type(b_over_n)` and checked it was of `'long'` type.

I have checked SageMath manuals but haven't found anything useful yet.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using Python2, where `int/int` would return `int`.
Thus since `b` was smaller than `n` in my case, `b/n` automatically returned `0`.